# Как изменить атрибут src у img при наведении

Tags: javascript, css

Как изменить атрибут src у img при наведении?Eсть-ли варианты реализации на чистом css?Если нет - то и js подойдёт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для `<img />`нужен `js`. Изображение при наведении можно задать в data атрибут, в котором будет лежать ссылка на второе изображение, а чтобы постоянно не обращаться к `dom`, можно хранить оба src в замыкании:

```js
function createHoverImage() {
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-hover-src]').forEach((img) => {
    const src = img.getAttribute('src');
    const srcH = img.getAttribute('data-hover-src');

    img.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {img.src = srcH;})
    img.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {img.src = src;})
  });
}

createHoverImage();
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF" data-hover-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000" />

<img id="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00" data-hover-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Через css можно при помощи `background` у элемента:

```css
div {
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/id/2/100/100');
}
div:hover {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

если все же нужен `img`, то через `js`

```js
img.addEventListener('mouseover', e => img.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/2/100/100");
img.addEventListener('mouseout', e => img.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100");
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100" />
```

Comment: salam, are you there?

Answer (score 1):

Пример с `content: url(...);` :

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img:hover {
  content: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562849227-64f2b4d72b9c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981408-db0ecd8a1ee4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
```

Но лучше все же через `background` или js.